# incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGRectContainsPoint'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

A long story short....

I get **incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGRectContainsPoint'** on the grid[x][y].frame part of all 3 if statements ([rubin1 frame], grid[x][y].frame), ([rubin2 frame], grid[x][y].frame) and ([rubin3 frame], grid[x][y].frame). I tried as well with [grid[x][y] frame] but got the same error.

I wanna be able to move around rubin 1, rubin2 and rubin3 on the grid until I release them on a brick. When I release them on the brick then I want this brick to disappear as well as any other of the same type as the brick that the rubin's where left on (no matter where they are on the grid)

```
for (int y = 0; y < BRICKHEIGHT; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < BRICKWIDTH; x++) 
    {


        if (CGRectContainsPoint([rubin1 frame], grid[x][y].frame)) {

            if(grid[x][y].tag == 1){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 2){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 3){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 4){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 5){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 6){

                ruby--;
                rubin1.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }


        } 
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([rubin2 frame], grid[x][y].frame)) {

            if(grid[x][y].tag == 1){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 2){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 3){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 4){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 5){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 6){

                ruby--;
                rubin2.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }

        } 
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([rubin3 frame], grid[x][y].frame)) {

            if(grid[x][y].tag == 1){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 2){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 3){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 4){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 5){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;
                [self PlayerScore: x y: y];

            }
            else if(grid[x][y].tag == 6){

                ruby--;
                rubin3.alpha = 0;
                grid[x][y].alpha = 0;





            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It expects a point as a second argument not a frame CGRect. Try grid[x][y].frame.origin. The origin gives you the top-right corner of the frame CGRect, and .size the width/height of the CGRect.

Comment: Hey again! I realised that I had done it the wrong way.. that's why it didn't work...  I used CGRectContainsPoint instead of using CGRectIntersectsRect. it works fine now. thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like this. Ex:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(myimage.frame, location) == 0){
//always end up here
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, other than making sure to reference a CGPoint instead of a CGRect - you also need to make sure the point is in the correct coordinate space. I would actually recommend using [touch locationInView:[grid[x][y] superview]]; That will compare the touch point to the coordinate space of the grid item container.

Comment: I see... thanks for the advice. I'll try it out tonight and let you know how it turned out :) by the way how can I get the rest of the code to remove all of the bricks on the grid that are of the same type as the one that I put the rubin on or does the example you showed me do that thing as well?

Comment: Hey again! I realised that I had done it the wrong way.. that's why it didn't work...  I used CGRectContainsPoint instead of using CGRectIntersectsRect. it works fine now. thanks for all the help